# Performing assertion after exception using EasyMock

Tags: java, testing, exception, assert, easymock

How can I test assertion immediately following an exception with EasyMock?
For example, there is a method `storeIntoFile()` which retrieves an object and writes it into a file. In case of an exception, this file is deleted. I'm looking to test this method specifically to verify that the file gets deleted on encountering an exception.
I have the following test to do this:

```
@Test (expected IOException.class)
public void testConnectionFailure throws IOException {
File storeFile = File.createTempFile(
        "test",
        "test"
    );
storeIntoFile(storeFile);
Assert.assertFalse(storeFile.exists());
}
```

However in this case, the test completes as soon as the exception is encountered during the `storeIntoFile` call and does not proceed to test the following assertion. How can I test this assertion after the exception without using mock objects?

Comment: All you need to do is run your `storeIntoFile(storeFile);` within a throws assertion, im sure your testing framework should support that.

Answer (score 0):

It's more a JUnit question than EasyMock. With JUnit 4.13, you can do the following.

```
public class MyTest {

    public interface FileRepository {
        void store(File file) throws IOException;
    }

    private void storeIntoFile(File file) throws IOException {
        try {
            repository.store(file);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            file.delete();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private final FileRepository repository = mock(FileRepository.class);

    @Test
    public void testConnectionFailure() throws IOException {
        File storeFile = File.createTempFile("test", "test");
        IOException expected = new IOException("the exception");

        repository.store(storeFile);
        expectLastCall().andThrow(expected);
        replay(repository);

        IOException actual = assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> storeIntoFile(storeFile));
        assertSame(expected, actual);
        assertFalse(storeFile.exists());
    }
}
```

I do not recommend the expected exceptions. assertThrows is much better since it allows to assert on the exception.